# How to change the color of the label text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with the code. I cannot change the font color of a specific value. For example, I would need to change the font color for DHL delivery only. I type the commands and either all delivery names change or none. Please help.

I have this html on my website

```css
#cart-options .delivery-container .delivery .name label, 
#cart-options .payment-container .delivery .name label {  
  color: #fa6161 !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;  
}
```

```html
<div id="cart-options">
<div class="delivery-container">
<div class="deliverycountry">
   <span colspan="3" class="desc">
   <em>Choose country:</em>
   </span>
   <span colspan="3" class="select">
      <select name="shipping_country">
         <option value="12">Austria</option>
      </select>
   </span>
   <span class="actions"></span>
</div>
<div >
   <h5>Dostawa:</h5>
   <div  data-engine="inpost" class="delivery selected first">
      <span class="name">
      <span class="radio-wrap">
      <input type="radio" name="shipping_id" id="shipping_20" value="20" checked="checked" />
      <label for="shipping_20"></label>
      </span>
      <label for="shipping_20">InPost</label>
      <span class="description">
      (text)
      </span>
      </span>
      <span class="value">
      13,50 zł
      </span>
   </div>
   <div  class="delivery">
      <span class="name">
      <span class="radio-wrap">
      <input type="radio" name="shipping_id" id="shipping_15" value="15" />
      <label for="shipping_15"></label>
      </span>
      <label for="shipping_15">DHL</label>
      <span class="description">
      (text)
      </span>
      </span>
      <span class="value">
      8,50 zł
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="payment-container">
<h5>
   Payment method:
</h5>
<div class="payment selected first">
   <span class="name">
   <span class="radio-wrap">
   <input type="radio" name="payment_id" id="payment_15" value="15" checked="checked" />
   <label for="payment_15"></label>
   </span>
   <label for="payment_15">
   Paypal
   </label>
   <span class="description">
   (description)
   <a id="online-payment" data-op-payment-id="15" class="js__online-payment">(wybierz Twój bank)</a>
   <input type="hidden" name="online_payment_gateway_id" id="online-payment-gateway-id" value="">
   <input type="hidden" id="online-payment-methods" value="code">
   </span>
   <span class="additional_cost_percent"></span>
   </span>
   <span class="value"></span>
</div>
<div class="payment">
   <span class="name">
   <span class="radio-wrap">
   <input type="radio" name="payment_id" id="payment_4" value="4" />
   <label for="payment_4"></label>
   </span>
   <label for="payment_4">
   cash
   </label>
   <span class="description">
   (cash)
   </span>
   <span class="additional_cost_percent"></span>
   </span>
   <span class="value"></span>
</div>
```

The only code that came out to me is this (but it changes the colors of all deliveries).

Comment: This question is unclear and messy.

Comment: You need something unique to identify the desired element by. If you are willing to hard-code this into your CSS, you can simply use the _attribute selector_ to directly access the label by the content of its `for` attribute; if not, then you need something else that makes this particular delivery method "identifiable" to begin with.

Comment: If the order in which these delivery methods are output is always the same (and there won't be any "missing" before the DHL one in any situations), then you could also use `:nth-child` to select the wrapping `. delivery` element first.

Comment: Please try not to use `!important` as it is a really bad practice, both performance-wise and making the code _not maintainable_.

Answer (score 2):

You could either style it inline like this `<label style="color:blue">DLH</label>`

Or you could make a seperate css class for this label